# Cloud Run - new database file needed each day in my app

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've a dockerized Spring Boot application and want to run it in Cloud Run.
Problem is I need to update db file each day (around ~1MB).

What options do I have?

- build new docker image each day using CD - risk of some fails during deployment, only db is changing
- download a file from Storage on start and each day - but I have no control over lifecycle of container
- pass as ENV variable - too big?

What do you think?

Comment: build a docker image each day, or whenever the file changes

Comment: You are building the database inside of the container if I understand correctly. This doesn't seems like a good idea. I would just load a new csv file into Cloud Storage each day. Giving us more context would also help here. Is your application idempotent? Is meant to run just one time per day and process the data?

Comment: @Chris32 downloading from Cloud Storage causes coldstart issue right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your code as-is, your solution is to build every day a new container. If you define correctly your Dockerfile, it's not so risky. Indeed, perform all the build step before and only add the db file on the latest layer of your container.

Like that, everyday, when you build your container, and if the previous layer are kept in cache (depends on your CI/CD platform), only the latest layer is replaced and the container build like that. Your code doesn't change, and you shouldn't have risk in packaging and deployment.

---

Your idea to have the db file on Cloud Storage isn't so good. Of course you have a versioning issue, but you also have a coldstart issue. Indeed, when your Cloud Run instance start, it has to download the file first, and then perform its normal start. Spring Boot is already very slow to start on Cloud Run, it's not a good idea to add external dependency and download latency on this cold start.

---

If you can work on your code, a .db file mean you have a SQL database (I don't know which one, a DB2 or SQLite maybe). If you use abstraction layer, such as Hibernate, it's easy to switch to another db engine, and thus to use Cloud SQL MySQL instance for example.

Of course, the cost isn't the same, but it's easier to manage the Cloud Run deployment. However, you still need to create a process (a CI/CD job?) to update and deploy the new data on Cloud SQL. The versioning can be also a concern (even if you can perform a snapshot manually in your CI/CD pipeline to save the Cloud SQL data before importing the new one.

Comment: What I called "database" it's actually a file with some raw data, without any structure. It's needs to be updated each day. The coldstart is the issue I have right now. The main problem with the building docker image each day using CI/CD is storing secrets in the repo (around 10 files with private keys) - I don't want to push them to repo, so need to find the way to somehow encrypt it and decrypt during CI/CD process.

Comment: You talk about a db file. For me, db stands for database!!

Comment: For your secret, why you don't use Secret Manager? And do you use secrets at build time, or only at runtime?

Comment: It is a db in a way it's stores the data I need. But I cannot convert it to mysql - it would have just a one row.

Comment: Secrets - just a runtime

Comment: what about using Pub/Sub to retrieve the newest "db" file?

Comment: If you use secret at runtime, I understand that you put in plain text the secret in the container, correct ? About PubSub, it's not a good idea. it's the same thing as Cloud Storage (you need to establish an external connection and to consume a message). And when a message is consumed in PubSub it disappear. Thus, if you start several Cloud Run instances, only the first one get the message and the other one haven't any message and db info.

Comment: Ok, so best option is to keep the secrets in the Secret Manager and build docker image each day. Isn't using Secret Manager causing same problems like Google Storage? Is it possible to put whole application.properties file as secret, load it and take use of Spring Boot annotations?  (instead of splitting as separated secrets and rewriting the code)

Comment: I recommend you to  have a look to the secret manager integration with Cloud Run. You can mount your secret as volume or as environment variables. It can solve your use case if you mount your secret property file as a volume and your set the correct path in your spring boot configuration (I think you can define the property file location in environment variables)